# How to do a simple binary left shift operation and binary to int conversion?

Tags: ruby

> **`<<`**   ***Binary Left Shift Operator.*** 
>   The left operands value is moved left by the number 
>           of bits specified by the right operand.

*Binary numbers:*

- 1 *is* 0001
- 2 *is* 0010
- 3 *is* 0011

*This is my understanding of how Binary left `<<` works:*

- `3 << 1` == `6` *and* (`6` == 0110) so since `3` *is* 0011 and `1` *is* 0001 what exactly is being "shifted" left? Is the second part of the equation just telling it how many zero's to shift left by? So `3 << 1` == `6` just means shift the binary of `3` left by `1` zero? Or `2 << 3` == `16` just means shift the binary of `2` left by `3` zeros?

**Questions:**

1. Is my understanding of binary left shift operator correct?
2. I can convert an `int` to binary using: `"%04b" % int`, but how do I go from binary to int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Left shift is exactly what it seems to be -- it isn't really bitwise like other operators that act on individual bits of each operand, << and >> operate on the individual bits of one using the whole of the other.
2. Try this: `"10".to_i(2)` -> 2

   The [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) method on string takes an argument for what base to interpret the object in. So, something like `"ff".to_i(16)` -> 255.

Comment: Works, what is the `(2)` ?

Comment: @feed_me_code: the base at the string is written in. 2 = binary, 10 = decimal, 16 = hex adjectival! and so on. Remember: all numbers on a computer are really just binary --  other representations are only textual.

Comment: hey thanks. I'm still unclear on that so I decided to ask it as a new question.